# How to backpress pass an activity?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that loads some content using an AsyncTask.

If the content is null then i launch an activty that contains a WebView to load the data.

The only problem is when i launch the activity using regular intents.

When the back button is pressed to return out of the WebView.

It returns to the following activity and the AsyncTask is ran again, and it does the same thing all over again.

I know how to Override the onBackPressed button. But what should i do to override this from happening each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is null then when you launch the second Activity (with the WebView) you should call `finish()` on the first Activity.

EDIT: Alternatively you should use `startActivityForResult` and then in the `onActivityResult` method invoke `finish()`.

Comment: So if i call finish what does this have to do with navigating back to it and then the AsyncTask running all over again?

Comment: Which i dont want. I want to go back to the activity before that. But the only problem is it is a listview loaded with dynamic data that can change depending on the item that was clicked.

Comment: If you call `finish` it will no longer be in the task stack, so the back press won't see it at all. You'll return to whatever spawned the Activity that starts the AsyncTask (which is your listview).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go back to the that loads the content, then call its `finish()` method after launching the WebView activity. The back button will then exit the app (or go to the activity before the loading one.)